# Facebook messenger in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-chat

I wanted to integrate a facebook messenger into my iPhone application.

Can anyone help me for the integration, I tried to use this https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios/blob/master/README.md

but this does not have any steps of integration, so it is pretty much complicated.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean by integrating facebook messenger.

If you are looking to share the content via facebook messenger
Then here is the code :

```
[FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/"] 
                                handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error) {
                                    // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                    // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error messaging link: %@", error.description]);
                                  } else {
                                    // Success
                                    NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                  }
                                }];
```

For more detail refer this :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No not sharing. I want to integrate the facebook chat in my own application. So that I can chat to friends from within my app.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get any direct solutions. I know how to send requests and invitations. And more over facebook doc says chat is meant for user to user communication not for apps to communicate.

But still There is chat Api using which it might be possible.